# What is the origin of this bizarre advert of people wearing swimsuits in a room with computer hardware?

Tags: magazine

This image of people wearing swimsuits in a room with computer hardware popped up on Twitter recently.

> [image: a woman wearing a swimsuit operating a computer in front, a man and a woman wearing swimsuits reading in the background]

Where was this advertisement published, and what computing product or service is it offering?

Comment: Implying sysadmin that has ever seen inside of gym

Comment: Not sure how the advert is 'sexist'when it features men and women!

Comment: Especially when the man is showing more skin than any of the women.

Comment: @arBemo58, look at the footwear.  The man is wearing comfortable slippers, while the woman is wearing "check out my legs" spike heels.

Comment: I Know It's Old,.... But Those Look Like Loafers To Me.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's advertising computer room air conditioning.

[image]

No doubt appeared in some late 1970's or early 1980's US-based computer magazine.  But exactly which one I couldn't find based on a little bit of searching for phrases and keywords in the full advertisement.

JdeBP reports the ad appearing in 1982 and 1983 in "Computer Decisions" magazine.  I could not find an on-line copy to confirm that but I did dig up a Google Books search that refers to the ad.

["Airflow" in Computer Decisions Volume 15](https://books.google.ca/books?redir_esc=y&id=141VAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=airflow)

[image]

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Nailing down the exact time frame would be nice, from the look of the equipment I'd think 1979s. Also the guy's shorts looks 70s style.

Comment: Telex and TWX but no Fax # is a clue to the timing - i.e., definitely no later than early 1980s.

Comment: [*Official Gazette of the United States Patent and Trademark Office*, Vol. 1033, Number 5 ("Trademarks"; August 30, 1983), page "TM 642"](https://books.google.com/books?id=IvXQAAAAMAAJ&pg=SL553-PA642&dq=DATAC), says of the "DATAC" mark: "For Computer Room Air Conditioners (U.S. Cl. 34). <newline> First use Jul. 16, 1982; in commerce Jul. 16, 1982". So, that puts a lower bound on the date. That, combined with manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact's comment, leaves a pretty narrow time-range. :-)

Comment: The publication is most likely a "trade rag" as indicated by the "Circle 102" at the bottom. At first I thought it might be from Datamation, but that seems to have used "Circle [num] on Reader Card" in the relevant time frame.

Comment: I Googled the company address - it is just a few miles from me - and that got a couple of references that also point to ~ 1983 or 1984.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact You know what you have to do. Drive out there and find that old guy that's been with the company forever, show him (yes, it will be a him) the ad and he'll hopefully dig out the actual magazine.

Comment: I used to work in Bangkok in an office that was previously used by IBM.  The floor that I was on used to house lots of equipment so it had a very powerful aircon. Even at tickover, it made the room a lot colder than most people wanted.  I was happy but the local staff kept jackets and sweaters in the office.  Being European, it seemed to odd for people to don more clothes as they entered the office.

Comment: Your upper bound might be off.  One can find 1987 versions of this blurb that advertise "_five_ basic series and _over 40_ models".  Presumably 6 basic types and 42 models is thus later than 1987.  Unless the figures were going down.  (-:

Comment: Apparently they were.  Further searching turns up volume 15 of _Computer Decisions_, Hayden Publishing, 1983; pages 77 and 163.  Page 163 has "circle 92", though.  For "circle 102" you want the same advertisement in volume 14 of _Computer Decisions_, also Hayden Publishing, 1982, page 179.

Comment: Great detective work! You will be giving us the name of the models next. Actually the guy looks kinda familiar from car ads.

Comment: @pipe My guess is that old guy will have a this ad ripped out of the magazine and posted on the back of his office door.

Comment: Here is a picture of a tape-drive very similar to those shown in the advert.

As you can see, they are IBM 3420

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz4U4.jpg

Answer (score 10):

I see DATAC on the advert. On googling I found the following:

*Since 1977, the DTAC commitment to the customer, a quality heavy equipment air conditioning product and specialized service has helped us grow into a reputable manufacturer of heat/cool systems for heavy equipment.
http://www.dtac.com/*

This tells you an earliest date for the advert. Furthermore they are a US firm so the computer is probably an IBM.

Here's an IBM 360. You can see that the console is a teletype so this is an earlier model than the one in your picture which has monitors.

[image]

I'm sure a little googling would track down the actual model. I don't have time to do it right now.

Comment: I love the old tape drives and classic style.  Makes me want to land a man on the moon by the end of the decade!

Comment: I don't think we can see the actual computer in the photo.  We *can* see a couple of vacuum-column tape drives in the background, which are definitely IBM style; they could be 3420s.  The terminals in the foreground could easily be IBM 3270s.

Comment: For some reason that equipment in the original ad screamed "DEC" to me. Perhaps the shade of blue.

Comment: @Chromatix The terminals are a pair of 3278s.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru I had the right series, then.  I think the case shape is about the same, but the keyboard is different.

Comment: @Chromatix - I've found a picture of a 3420. See my latest answer.